# How to update a Google Chrome "Speed Dial" thumb?

Tags: google-chrome, thumbnails, speed-dial

"Speed Dial" is the New Tab page in Google Chrome, where it shows thumbnails, which are links the most visited sites.

One of the sites drastically changes its appearance and I want that the thumb to be updated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on a thread in the [Google Chrome Help Forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=311a3a33c39624f5&hl=enBlockquote):

1. Quit Google Chrome.
2. Go to *Start » Run* and type:

   - Windows XP:
     `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\`
   - Windows Vista:
     `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\`
3. Open *Default* folder and delete *Top Sites* and *Top Sites-journal*.

This will remove all the thumbnails, but Chrome will rebuild them.

Comment: Tried it today and it worked; However, the files to delete are now "Top Sites" and "Top Sites-journal", instead of "Thumbnails".

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer. In the future please feel free to suggest an edit to correct such minor things.

Comment: @slhck Does this trick still work ? I tried and my thumbnails didn't get updated.

Answer (score 1):

I actually suffered from the same thing yesterday, when updating my blog. Unlike the thumbnails in Opera (where you can add your own thumbnails), those in Chrome show "Most Visited" sites by default, unless you pin a site you like. What you should do is unpin the thumbnail you want updated, and visit the site several times (3 did it in my case) and you'd get the updated look and feel.